# ods excel and proc template

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I am running into an error when trying to use `ods excel` after defining a style named `excel` via `ods template`.  I was wondering if anyone could explain why this is happening as I thought ods styles and ods destinations were two completely separate things.

The following `ods excel` statement works fine:

```
ods excel file="%sysfunc(pathname(work))\x.xlsx";
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods excel close;
```

But if I try to run it after running the below `proc template` code, I get an error.

```
proc template;
  define style excel; 
    parent=styles.htmlblue;
    class graph       / attrpriority='none';
    style graphdata1  / contrastColor=#416FA6 markersymbol='circlefilled';
    style body from body / pagebreakhtml=_undef_; * REMOVE THE HORIZONTAL RULE;
  end; 
run; 

ods excel file="%sysfunc(pathname(work))\x.xlsx";
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods excel close;
```

The error is:

```
ERROR: Could not find method.
ERROR: No body file. EXCEL output will not be created.
```

I can just rename my style to something other than `excel` to fix the issue, but I don't understand why this is happening in the first place.  Is anyone able to explain?  Thanks.

Comment: Is the error from PROC TEMPLATE? or PROC PRINT?  Also I don't see any attempt to use the new style.

Comment: @tom The error is from the `ods excel` statement I believe.  And correct - no attempt to use the new style is necessary for this to start triggering the error.

Comment: I can confirm that this creates an error but not sure why. Tested in 9.4M6

Comment: What happens if you use `styles.excel` instead of `excel` for the path name?

Comment: @Tom Yup - that fixes it.  If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.  I guess there's some kind of naming conflict going on that fully qualifying it avoids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments, thanks @Tom:

Use `ods styles.excel` instead of `ods excel`:

```
ods styles.excel file="%sysfunc(pathname(work))/x.xlsx";
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods styles.excel close;
```